# IIS get full error message for failed requests

Tags: iis-7.5, windows, wcf, iis

I have IIS set-up and serving my webservice. Unfortunately if the webservice throws an exception, all I get is a blue box with the title failed request.

What options do I have to actually see what went wrong? I'd prefer to get the exception message and a stack trace.

I already set-up "Failed Request Tracing" but the directory remains empty. If possible I'd prefer to get the stack trace in the browser directly.

Just if this matters: I have an IIS 7.5 on a Win 7 64 Pro box. The Webservice is a WCF C# project.

Comment: Is the information in [WCF Error Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg281715%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) any use?

Answer (score 7):

You will find the errors in the eventlog, but having them in the browser is indeed more convenient (especially during development). To do that: turn on [debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your `web.config`. Also, switch [custom errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) off or set them to `"Remote only"`.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your service behavior in ***web.config:***

```
 <behavior name="Your.Service.Type">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
 </behavior>
```

Comment: What is "Your.Service.Type"?

Comment: Mmmm... according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dayb112d.aspx there's no <behavior> tag. Where should I put this?

Comment: It's in this path: <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

Comment: I managed to add this to the web.config. Unfortunately it breaks the service completely request to the webserver are not answered anymore.